# How to get parent object in Realm

Tags: java, android, database, relational-database, realm

[Reference](https://realm.io/docs/java/0.75.0/) to realms doc

I have some entities, for example it is: **Category** and **Item**.
 The Category contains **RealmList** of **Items** and I can access all items of category by calling getter of this list.
 But how can I query all **items** by category's id(it's annotated as primary key)
I'm parsing json via Realm.createObjectFromJson() and can't set **Category** field to each **Item**
Thanx in advance

Comment: Realm JS Issue for this: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/343

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there isn't any link from your `Item` to your `Category` you cannot currently query Items based on the Category. The concept you are looking for is on our TODO and is called backlinks. You can follow progress on that here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607

The current workaround would be to manually create that link after you copied them to Realm:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
Category category = realm.createObjectFromJson(categoryJson);
for (Item item : category.getItems()) {
  item.setCategory(category);
}
realm.commitTransaction();

// Then you can do
realm.where(Item.class).equalTo("category.id", category.getId()).findAll();
```

Comment: or at least automatically set the category field for each of Category's Items (if that field exists in Item class) while parsing

Comment: Yes, that is actually idea behind backlinks, that they will be set automatically.

Comment: I thought "category.id" was the fieldname how is there a period in the field name?

Comment: Backlinks are already available.
https://proandroiddev.com/realm-backlinks-queries-to-linking-objects-and-changes-in-schema-design-d64de74f1608